# Why value of equation has undefined at the end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I write simple calculator in JS & jQuery and I've come across strange behaviour. In code below, you see variable *equation* which holds every number pressed on calculator. I then use `eval()` to well, evaluate.

Issue is, that value of *equation* variable is what you'd expect BUT with *undefined* at the end, and cannot figure out why.

Whole project here: http://codepen.io/ketus/full/XmYRoV/

Thanks for help in advance!

PS.: I know general opinion about `eval()`. It is used only for testing so I can get moving. I will implement my own solution after solving problem with *undefined*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  
  var equation = '';
  var input = $('h2[data-value]');  
  var info = $('#info');
  //get keys
  var keys = $('.key').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('key');
  }).get();  
  
  //get operators
  var operators = $('.operator').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('operator');
  }).get();    
  
  //Clearing input
  $('.clear').click(function(){
    equation = '';
    input.html('');
    info.html('');
  });  
  
  //user press keys, check if correct after each click 
  $('.key').click(function(){
    equation += $(this).data('key');  
    //evaluateEquation();
    input.html(equation);    
  });   
  
  //showing result
  $('a[data-calc]').click(function(){
    input.html(eval(equation.toString()));
  }); 
  
  // rules for equation to be correct
  //function evaluateEquation()  {    
  //}
  
  function calculate(){    
    if(equation.length > 0){    
      return eval(equation);
    } else { 
      info.html('Enter something!');
      return '';
    } 
  }
  
});
```

Comment: There is no `data-key` for the equal button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is with user press event handler. You should not append `data('key')` if `=` was pressed. For example you can exclude this button like this:

```
  //user press keys, check if correct after each click 
  $('.key:not([data-calc])').click(function(){
    equation += $(this).data('key');  
    input.html(equation);    
  });
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOKwOE?editors=101

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!